# python code error at calculation

Tags: python-3.x

```
print ('welcome to the new world')
print('what is your name')
myName = input()
print ('it is good to meet you , ' + myName)
print (' Th length of your name is : ')
print (len(myName))
print('what is your age')
myEdge = input()
print ('you were born on ,')
print (2018 - myEdge)
```

The above code fails at last line.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "C:\Users\Pratik\Desktop\python\First_Program.py", line 10, in <module>
    print (2018 - myEdge)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

But I can run it manually by assigning value and it is running while we convert the variable data type to string print (2018 - int(myEdge))

confused why difference between script and command line execution

> > > myEdge = 29
> > >       print ( 2018 - myEdge )
> > >       1989

Answer (score 0):

In line command :

```
myEdge = 29 # You put an integer in the variable
```

In script :

```
myEdge = input("Enter your age -> ") # You put a string in the variable
```

It's why you have a difference between line command and script.
You have the solution for the script `int(myEdge)` . For the tips you can add text into the input : `input("add_the_text_here")` .

Moreover in line command you can test the same :

```
>>> t = input(">")
>29
>>> type(t)
<class 'str'>
>>> 30 - t
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    30 - t
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```